# How do I generate a column array starting from a specific value and with a set number of elements and stepping?

Tags: matlab

I need to generate a new array to append to an array of intensities from an EDS intensity file.  The data I am given is the initial value of -40, the spacing between elements 9, and I know the number of data points is 2048.  I am extremely new to MATLAB so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to initialise an array from the data you have

```
start = -40;
step  = 9;
n = 2048;
```

You could simply add an array of `n` multiples of `step`, i.e.

```
arr = (0:n-1)*step + start;
```

Or you could find the end value and make an array to meet it

```
stop = start + step*(n-1);
% equivalent:
arr = linspace( start, stop, n );
% or
arr = start:step:stop;
```

All of the above make row vectors, to get a column you can transpose them (surround with brackets and use the transpose operator `.'`) like so:

```
arr = ((0:n-1)*step + start).';
```